# How do I run inetd at startup on OpenBSD?

Tags: rsync, openbsd, inetd

I am trying to backup my Synology NAS to my old NAS. The old NAS has to be an rsync compatible server (according to Synology), and the original OS didn't support it. Fortunately OpenBSD supports my NAS ('landisk', well done!), and I managed to get `rsync` running in daemon mode.

I read the option to launch `rsync` via `inetd`. I thought this would be the best option. I followed the instructions in the man pages. Everything is done under the root account.
The line

```
rsync           873/tcp
```

was already in my `/etc/services`.

I created `/etc/inetd.conf` and added the line

```
rsync   stream  tcp     nowait  root   /usr/local/bin/rsync rsyncd --daemon
```

Then I had to send a HUP signal to inetd. But with `ps -A` I didn't see `inetd` running.

So I added the line

```
inetd=YES
```

to `rc.conf.local`, which looks now like this:

```
ntpd_flags=
inetd=YES
```

When I enter inetd at the CLI  everything works fine. But when I `reboot` the NAS, `inetd` is not running. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the lack of reactions, I posted my question on another forum.

And [there](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?p=54701&posted=1#post54701) I got the answer!

This is what my /etc/rc.conf.local now looks like:

```
ntpd_flags=
inetd_flags=
inetd=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle services and daemons on an OpenBSD system (since OpenBSD 5.7) is by using [`rcctl(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/rcctl):

To enable `inetd` and `ntpd` (assuming you have configured `doas` to give you superuser rights):

```
$ doas rcctl enable inetd
$ doas rcctl enable ntpd
```

To start `inetd` and `ntpd` without rebooting (requires a valid `/etc/inetd.conf` and `/etc/ntpd.conf`):

```
$ doas rcctl start inetd
$ doas rcctl start ntpd
```

The `rsync` port comes with `/etc/rc.d/rsyncd`, which means that you may enable and start the `rsync` daemon through

```
$ doas rcctl enable rsyncd
$ doas rcctl start rsyncd
```

This requires that you first create `/etc/rsyncd.conf`.